# What are the perfect squares for $a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I have been writing a python program to generate integers that satisfy the perfect root of $a^2 + b^2$ over large ranges of values using brute force loops. Are there direct generating equations to solve this problem?

Just to be clear, for example, $a = 16$ and $b=30$ form a perfect square, since $\sqrt{16^2+30^2}=34$. So is $a=1308$ and $b=3815$, and so on.

In my searching, I read how Euclid solved the Diophantine equations for pythagorean triples and I thought the method would apply to my situation.

I thought that if $a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfied the triple $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $a^2+b^2$ is a perfect square and would be given by the same equations of Euclid. Namely,
$a=m^2-n^2$, $b=2mn$. And indeed, this is the case for $a=16$ and $b=30$ where $m=5$ and $n=3$. Success, I thought!
But there is no rational solution for $a=1308$ and $b=3815$ or any of the other $a,b$ pairs as per some fiddling on wolframalpha.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: have you searched google http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/trip.html is one such list ( though I had to use my bookmark manager to find it again) BTW n=1 m=2 produces a=3,b=4

Comment: Euclid's equations generate every pythagorean triple where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. In your example, $a=1308$ and $b=3815$ have common factor $109$, which is why they are not so generated. (But $a=12$, $b=35$ — which can be obtained from your example by dividing through by the common factor — is generated by Euclid's equations: take $m=6$, $n=1$.)

Comment: Applying Jack D'Aurizio's answer to your purported counter-example the  $\gcd(1308,3815)=109$.  The primitive Pythagorean Triple is $12^2+35^2 = 37^2$.  This gives $m=\sqrt{\frac{35+37}{2}}=6$ and $n=\frac{12}{2\cdot 6}=1$.

Comment: @Micah - I see, I didn't realize my list was not primitive. This makes total sense now. Thanks

Comment: https://youtu.be/QJYmyhnaaek I personally like this video by 3Blue1Brown. It talks about Pythagorean triples in a way to "visualize" all of them.

Comment: In $34^2 = 16^2 + 30^2$ can be rewritten as $34^2= (4+30)^2=4^2 + 2*4*30 + 30^2$. This is just one decomposition of $34^2$ into $(a+b)^2= a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. If you add up $4^2 +2*4*30$ you get $16 + 240=256 = 16^2$. So one of the squares is a sum of $a^2 and 2ab$. If you start with $34$, you just decompose it until you get a sum of two squares. If you start with $16^2 + 30^2$, you have two cases to consider since either one of the two squares is a sum of $a^2 + 2ab$ or $b^2 + 2ab$. For example $65^2=33^2 + 56^2$ has the following decomposition: (cont next comment).

Comment: (cont)- $65= (32+33)^2 =32 ^2 + 2*32*33 + 33^2= 33^2 + 56^2$ with  $56^2 + 32^2 + 2*32*33= 56^2$. In fact $65$ has another decomposition that leads to $65^2=39^2 +52^2$ with $39^2=13^2 + 2*13*52$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure of Pythagorean triples is well-known. Let us consider the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and a line with rational slope through $(1,0)$: by Vieta's theorem the second intersection with the circle is a point with rational coordinates, and if $P(x,y)\neq(1,0)$ is a point on the unit circle with rational coordinates the line joining $P$ with $(1,0)$ has a rational slope. By computing in a explicit way the non-trivial intersection between $x^2+y^2=1$ and a line through $(1,0)$ with slope $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ we get that

> Every rational point $P(x,y)$ on $x^2+y^2=1$ is of the form $x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, y=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ for some $t\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Every rational point on $x^2+y^2=1$ is associated with a Pythagorean triple by
$$ \left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c}\right)\in S^1 \mapsto (a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}^3, a^2+b^2=c^2.$$
In particular:

> *Corollary*: if $a,b,c$ are positive integers such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$, up to switching $a$ and $b$ we have
>   $$ a = d(2pq),\quad b=d(p^2-q^2),\quad c=d(p^2+q^2) $$
>   with $d\geq 1$, $p\geq q\geq 1$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and at least one number between $p,q$ being even.

This generates the whole set of Pythagorean triples, and the constraint $d=1$ gives the primitive pythagorean triples.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment about its downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but maybe they didn't follow the concept or relevance of "rational points." Your second paragraph isn't very obvious - maybe the geometry merits elaboration?

Comment: Right, I was just suggesting that might be put explicitly in the answer. (i.e. solving $y = tx, x^2 + y^2 = 1$ directly)

Comment: @Chris: suggestion accepted and answer updated, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the constraint "at least one number between p, q being even" - is this a redundant observation from the previous constraints?

Comment: @Stoddard: it is not redundant if you want that the case d=1 generates the primitive triples. With (d,p,q)=(1,3,5) the generated triple is not primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's formula generates *primitive* Pythagorean triples.  Your example, $b = 2 m n = 1308, a = m^2 - n^2 = 3815$ has no solution in integers because $\gcd(a,b) = 109$.  (Note that $b = 2 m n$ always has to be the even member of the pair.)  For primitive Pythagorean triples, $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.  The primitive triple with $a = 3815/109 = 35$ and $b = 1308/109 = 12$ is given by $m = 6, n = 1$.

To get *all* Pythagorean triples, use $a = g(m^2 - n^2), b = g(2 m n)$, where $g$ is the common factor of $a$ and $b$ and is allowed to range over all positive integers, and $m$ and $n$ range over all positive integers with $m > n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are, in fact, ways to generate infinitely many pythagorean triples. Suppose we have $$a,b,c \in \mathbb N$$

**METHOD 1:** Let $a$ be some odd number. Then set
$$b=\frac{a^2-1}{2}$$
and set
$$c=\frac{a^2+1}{2}$$
Ta da! $a^2+b^2=c^2$!

**METHOD 2:** Let $a \ge 8$ be some doubly even number. Then set
$$b=\frac{a^2}{4}-1$$
and
$$c=\frac{a^2}{4}+1$$
Ta da! Even more pythagorean triples!

These are both proven to work easily; however, I have not figured out how to prove or disprove that *all* pythagorean triples can be generated by one of these two methods.

Does this help?